# How do I exclude alphabetic characters & numbers beginning with zero, using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a class that initiate this function...but I need to modify it's regex.

I would like to exclude all alphabetic characters and any numbers beginning with 0[zero].

```
$('.numeric').keyup(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('field-error', /(0|00|000)$/.test(this.value));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){                          
   $('#test_regex').click( function(){
      regex= /^[a-zA-Z0]+$/;
      str= $('#reginput').val();
      result= regex.test(str);
      if( result ){
        alert("Value contains alphabet or begin with zero number");
      }else{
        alert("It's the correct value");
      }
  });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="reginput"/>
<button id="test_regex">Check Value</button>
```

Maybe it's what you want...

Comment: I took the the `+$` off the end of the regex and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a regex that can detect non digit characters and leading zeroes in the field. The regex below maybe of help

```
[^\d]+|^0
```

This regex when used with test function will return true if the string contains any non digit character or if it starts with digit zero. ^[a-zA-Z0]+$ will not match the string "123asd562"